# Mesh following bone with strange offset

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have a multi-layer armature with a FK- weightpaint layer following a IK control layer.  I weight paint it to a test armature and everything looks fine...except the feet.  For whatever reason, the feet are offset from the bone in such a way where the block character walks bow-legged:

[image]

Note that all bones are visible here, and the weight painting is what I need it to be.  The foot mesh even follows the bone...albeit a few units offset.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Generally, this happens when two or more bones are affecting the same mesh part. Some other bones other than the ones you need, might have weights also affecting the same leg too, check on the right or any nearby bone to see if it has weights assigned to that leg.

Comment: An audit of the bones along with pressing N in edit/vertex mode showed nothing I wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the rest positions for those bones were wrong.  This was extremely hard for me to detect because the mesh layer was following the control layer in pose mode.  To catch it, I looked at the armature with all layers turned on in edit mode.